# LDAP: error code 49 - Simple Bind Failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE

Tags: java, spring, ldap, jndi, spring-ldap

I am trying to authenticate the user but it throws `Exception`.May be there is problem in configuration.

```
public class LdapApplication {
private static final String INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY = "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory";
private static final String SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION ="simple";
private static final String NAMED_CONTEXT = "CN=Users";
private static final String SAM_ACCOUNT_NAME = "sAMAccountName=";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();

    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://ip:portNo/dc=organisation,dc=in");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=userName,cn=Users");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password" );
    DirContext context = null;

    NamingEnumeration namingEnumeration = null;
    try {
        context = new InitialDirContext(env);

        namingEnumeration = context.search(NAMED_CONTEXT, SAM_ACCOUNT_NAME+ userName, null);
        while (namingEnumeration.hasMore()) {
            SearchResult searchResult = (SearchResult) namingEnumeration.next();
            Attributes attributes = searchResult.getAttributes();

            System.out.println(" Person Common Name = " + attributes.get("cn"));
          System.out.println(" Person Display Name = " + attributes.get("displayName"));

            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (namingEnumeration != null) {
            try {
                namingEnumeration.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        if (context != null) {
            try {
                context.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

but if i mention  `Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL` as `"organisation\\userName"` instead of `"cn=userName,cn=Users"` it works perfectly fine. Kindly suggest a possible solution because my requirement is to give SECURITY_PRINCIPAL something using cn or dc.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a relative distinguished name which will not work.

Change your code to use

```
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=userName,cn=Users,dc=organisation,dc=in");
```

and also change your search context to:

```
private static final String NAMED_CONTEXT = "CN=Users,dc=organisation,dc=in";
```

Always use full distinguished names with LDAP.

Comment: One thing I want to tell you that my `DN : "CN= User Name, CN=Users,dc=organisation,dc=in"` and my 'sAMAccountName: userName'. I want to use `sAMAccountName` in order to authenticate user

Comment: Then you will have to search for it using a proxy user first, in order to resolve the FDN. To my knowledge `sAMAccountName` is not a LDAP naming attribute in AD, iow you cannot use `sAMAccountName=userName,cn=Users,dc=organisation,dc=in`.

Answer (score 2):

We were having the same issue in our code and we fixed it by adding the domain name before the user name. Instead  of entering `user:password`, enter `domain\user:password`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To do an LDAP bind you will need to use one of the a Unique return for one of the Ambiguous Name Resolution entries. Normally, one would use the Fully Distinguished name.

We have a [JNDI Example showing how this could be done.](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Basic%20JNDI%20Search%20with%20Administration%20Account)

-jim