# Connect to AD using credentials from Linux Server

Tags: java, linux, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to connect to an active directory server using credentials that were created for a linux server. There's a web interface on the server for providing the credentials and I'm unable to connect with the credentials I'm providing.  To troubleshoot I'm just trying to connect from my local machine in Java using the same method the code on the server is using.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {

        final String ldapAdServer = "ldap://server:port";
        final String ldapSearchBase = "OU=Users,OU=xxx,DC=yyy,DC=zzz,DC=aaa,DC=com";

        final String ldapUsername = "user";
        final String ldapPassword = "password";

        final String ldapAccountToLookup = "lookup";
        final String dc = ",DC=yyy,DC=zzz,DC=aaa,DC=com";
        final String ou = ",OU=Uncommon Users,OU=xxx";

        Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        if(ldapUsername != null) {
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "CN=" + ldapUsername + ou + dc);
        }
        if(ldapPassword != null) {
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, ldapPassword);
        }
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapAdServer);

        // the following is helpful in debugging errors
        //env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.trace.ber", System.err);

        LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
        ConnectLdap ldap = new ConnectLdap();

        try {
            ldap.findUsers(ctx, ldapSearchBase);
            ldap.findAccountByAccountName(ctx, ldapSearchBase, ldapAccountToLookup);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

there are many questions out there with similar problems like this one [Java ldap authentication issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512258/java-ldap-authentication-issue) for which cn should be used instead of uid. This one [Randomly getting LDAP Error 49, data 52e on random users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23303017/randomly-getting-ldap-error-49-data-52e-on-random-users) and this one [LDAP + Java Aplication Authentication error code 49 - 52e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24999878/ldap-java-aplication-authentication-error-code-49-52e) where the AD does not allow anonymous binding which I don't think I'm trying to do since I'm providing the username and password.  This one [LDAP: error code 49 - Simple Bind Failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22383624/ldap-error-code-49-simple-bind-failed-nt-status-logon-failure) where the problem is trying to connect using a relative distinguished name which I also don't think I'm doing.  I can connect using this username and password with a client, navigate to the user I connected with and get the full distinguished name of the user.  This full dn is what I'm providing in the security_principal, what am I missing?

Here is the exception which occurs when trying to construct the InitialLdapContext

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1
```

Comment: "...and I'm unable to connect..." - we're going to need a bit more than that. What error message/code do you get back? Is there an exception or stack trace available?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to post the excpetion, just added it

Comment: There is a space in one of my OU's, according to this article http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5312.active-directory-characters-to-escape.aspx you only need to escape leading and trailing spaces

Comment: Also tried CN=server\username and uid={0} in place of CN with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "CN=" + ldapUsername + ou + dc);
```

should be

```
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, ldapUsername@dc1.dc2.dc3.dc4);
```

if you're using a client its the userPrincipalName in the properties of the user

Comment: This is not necessary, AD allows LDAP binds with the UPN, but a 'normal' bind would use the qualified DN just like the OP is doing.